# How to receive multipart file upload using reactor-netty (without Spring)?

Tags: reactor-netty

I've seen there is exemples with reactor-netty on how to post files using multipart form (https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/89796a1839a1439a1800424e130515357a827392/src/test/java/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClientTest.java#L337)

But I couldn't find any information on how to write a server using reactor-netty that can parse multipart information.

It seems that netty is able to do it using `HttpPostRequestDecoder` class but I cannot see where it fits...

I also seen `InterfaceHttpData` is a mother class of `Attributes` and `FileUpload` but I don't see where I can obtain these objects from the request...

Has anyone ever done this? Any clues?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```java
request.receive()
  .aggregate()
  .flatMap(byteBuf -> {
    FullHttpRequest dhr = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(request.version(), request.method(), request.uri(), byteBuf, request.requestHeaders(), EmptyHttpHeaders.INSTANCE);
    HttpPostRequestDecoder postDecoder = new HttpPostRequestDecoder(new DefaultHttpDataFactory(false), dhr, CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
    // loop data
    for (InterfaceHttpData data : postDecoder.getBodyHttpDatas()) {
        // attribute
        if (data.getHttpDataType() == InterfaceHttpData.HttpDataType.Attribute) {
            // (MemoryAttribute) data
        }
        // upload
        else if (data.getHttpDataType() == InterfaceHttpData.HttpDataType.FileUpload) {
            // (MemoryFileUpload) data
        }
    }
    postDecoder.destroy();
    dhr.release();
  });
```

Comment: I didn't get the data I wanted from Request, but I think it's also possible to create HttpPostRequestDecoder with Request information and then get POST content from Decoder.